# The generators in the definition of Grassmann Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, algebras

The definition of the Grassmann algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ with $L$ generators is (from Rogers book on Supermanifolds)

[image]

[image]

My problem with this: we never say what these generators are. Do they exist even? For example, when we define the operations for the elements of $\mathbb{N}$, for example, we are in solid grounds, since the natural numbers can be defined using sets, in such a way that their existence is assured (if one accepts the axioms of set theory, of course). In this case, we are describing how the multiplication of generators work, but we have not defined the generators at all.

Maybe my question is a non-question somehow, but it is boggling me.

Comment: How much abstract algebra do you know?

Comment: You can think of Grassman algebra as a multivariate polynomial ring with multiplications between different dummy variables satisfying anticommutation rather than commutation rules. You can say dummy variables do not exist. They are just symbols. But we can still construct a polynomial ring in terms of them.

Comment: @Chappers Not much: I did one course on group theory. Everything I learned besides that was self taught.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe That certainly seems to be the solution for my problems. Could you please elaborate on your comment in an answer? I am not familiar with "multivariate polynomial ring" and the precise meaning of "with multiplications between different dummy variables satisfying anticommutation rather than commutation rules" is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar example to Grassmann algebra is the polynomial. In abstract algebra, polynomials of a symbol $x$ (or dummy variable) over a field (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) form a ring structure. See for example,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring

In the polynomial ring, polynomials are not understood as functions of $x$, but expressions. The variable $x$ in a polynomial, e.g., $1-2x+x^3$ is not understood as a number but only as a symbol. The insistence on this point does not seem so necessary for polynomials, as you do get a number from the polynomial when you plug in a number to $x$. But this "symbolic" understanding of polynomials helps generalizing the concept of them to formal power series. See for example,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series

The infinite series of the symbol $x$ is only an expression. This saves the worry of convergence issues. One can write down e.g. $1+x+2!x^2+\cdots+n!x^n+\cdots$ as a formal power series with no problem, even though the convergence radius of the infinite series is $0$, which means the infinite series is not well defined for all $\,x\neq 0\,$ when understood as a function.
Of course, there has to be stricter rules towards how to manipulate these formal expressions so that the result is always well defined.

It's a bit of digression to talk about formal power series. But the symbolic view of the variable $x$ in polynomials helps us understand the Grassmann algebra. Before that, let's think about a polynomial ring of two symbols $x$ and $y$. Even though we don't know what $x$ and $y$ represent, we do assume $xy=yx$ to deal with multiplications such as $(x+y)(x-y)=x^2-y^2$. Otherwise the $xy$ term and $yx$ term do not cancel. Even for one symbol $x$, we need to assume $xx^2=x^2x=x^3$. If the multiplication of the symbol is not associative, a polynomial of $x$ is not well-defined either.

As opposed to a multivariate polynomial ring, the Grassmann algebra makes a different assumption of how the multiplication between the symbols $x$ and $y$ works. Instead of assuming $xy=yx$, the multiplication between symbols (or generators) of the Grassmann algebra anticommute, i.e., $xy=-yx$. Not only that, a symbol also anticommutes with itself, i.e., $x^2=-x^2=0$. So the most general object of a Grassmann algebra with $2$ symbols $x$ and $y$ is given by the expression

$$a+bx+cy+dxy,$$

where $a,b,c,d$ are numbers in the field over which the Grassmann algebra is defined. They can be real numbers, complex numbers, etc. The symbols $x$ and $y$ do not belong to these fields. They are just the symbols. So multiplications between the coefficients $a,b,c,d$ commute as normal real or complex numbers do, while mutliplications between the symbols $xy=-yx$ anticommute. A multiplication of two objects in the Grassmann algebra is given by
\begin{align}
&(a_1+b_1x+c_1y+d_1xy)(a_2+b_2x+c_2y+d_2xy)\\
=a_1a_2+(a_1&b_2+a_2b_1)x+(a_1c_2+a_2c_1)y+(b_1c_2-b_2c_1+a_1d_2+a_2d_1)xy.
\end{align}
We can also have Grassmann algebra over quaternion fields. Then the coeffcients $\,a,b,c,d\,$ in general do not commute. One step at a time.

Comment: While I don't see anything formally wrong with creating a Grassman algebra (or even a Clifford algebra) with coefficients from division rings, strictly speaking it is a departure from normal *algebras*. The problem is that the axioms for algebras require the set of scalars to be central in the ring, and that is not the case for division rings that aren't fields. For Clifford algebras, things are even a little worse because bilinear forms don't work nicely with division rings. Anyhow, one must tread carefully when calling something an algebra over a division ring.

Comment: The thing that goes wrong is that you can't ensure that $\lambda (ab) = (\lambda a)b=a(\lambda b)$ for all scalars $\lambda$. But it is interesting to try, nonetheless.

Comment: I think in the definition (3.1), it is assumed that the generator "1" commutes with all Grassmann generators. So perhaps there is already some restriction there.

Comment: @zhuranhe Yes, $1$ is one of the generators he mentions, after all. But it doesn't say anything about how the scalars behave. I think he is implicitly assuming they commute with everything.

Comment: The "symbolic" view of polynomials is quite crucial to polynomial theory. There are only four functions $\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}_2$, but there is an unlimited number of (univariate) polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 2):

There are typically two constructions put forward to explain Grassman algebras (and also Clifford algebras, which are similar.)

One is the "bottom-up" version where you just assert that there are these symbols that multiply with such-and-such rules, and the object they form is called the Grassman algebra. There's not really anything wrong with this, and it's pretty simple, but it makes some students uneasy (I think I sense a little bit of this in your post text).

The "top-down" explanation takes another approach. For a field $k$, it takes the free algebra in $n$ indeterminates $R=k\langle x_1,x_2\ldots, x_n\rangle$, generates an ideal $I$ containing the relations that you want to hold for the Grassman algebra, and then $R/I$ is the Grassman algebra, because it satisfies all the rules you wanted in the bottom-down approach.

Some students prefer the latter one since it is easy to imagine that free algebras exist (since they are like polynomial rings with indeterminates that don't commute) and then the quotient is a concrete thing.

Comment: I am interested in that question, too. What is the "bottom-up" version for the Clifford algebra? I just find the "top down" versions on the web. How could we find out the dimension of those algebras?

Comment: @user372565 Interested in what question? The posted question here? As for what I mean about "bottom up", just what I said in the second paragraph. They declare the basis and establish how they multiply by fiat, and then extend linearly.  That's probably the more common method, afaict.

Comment: But you will need a quadratic form for this, won't you? Normally we fix a vetor spave $V$ and a quadratic form $q$. Then Clifford algebra is the quotient of the tensor algebra and the two-sided ideal generated by elements $v\otimes v -q(v)1$, $v\in V$. So the other definition would be: It is the algebra generated by $a_1,...,a_n$ with relations $a_i²=q(a_i)$. Is this right?

Comment: @user372565 Yes, you'd need a quadratic form to define the Clifford algebra either way. In the case of the Grassman algebra it's just the trivial form with $q(v)=0$ uniformly.  "The other definition" meaning the "top down one" would be the quotient of the tensor algebra by the ideal generated by the appropriate generators. With the fiat version, readers apparently don't have to worry about the details of what a quotient is.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. There is another way, isn't it? Namely: Let $S=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ and $k[S]$ the algebra generated by $S$. The Grassmann algebra is $k[S]$ modulo the ideal generated by elements $v²$. Conserning this definition, where does $v$ live? In $S$, in the $k$-span of $S$ or in $k[S]$? I would think in the $k$-span, because in the definition above which involves a vector space we would choose any vector space with basis $S$.

Comment: @user372565 That is precisely the top-down method. The generators for the ideal are of the form $v\otimes v - q(v)$ for every $v$ in the underlying vector space, and when the quadratic form is uniformly zero, you get what you got.  So yes, in your construction you would need $V=\langle S\rangle$. In general, with some random set, I wouldn't really call that a Grassman algebra. I doubt it has all the requisite interpretation.

Comment: But where is the difference to you explained top-down method? As far as I see you have taken the random set $S=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$. So what's different here? 

Why the relations in the OP were just defined on generators and not for the underlying vector-space? Does this gives another notion for Graßmann algebra?

Comment: @user372565 If you know how quotients work, then of course, there is no difference. Would you say that defining Hamilton's quaternions with $i,j,k$ and their multiplications is the same as defining it with a quotient? Technically, yes, but from the viewpoint of a student, that is bottom-up, involving "no quotients."